# i have an error in cake Notice (8): Undefined variable: html [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 6]

Tags: php, cakephp

#### Notice (8): Undefined variable: html [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 6]

### Fatal error: Call to a member function css() on a non-object in D:\Xampp\htdocs\mvc\cakephp\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 6

in defult.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tasks</title>
    <?php echo $this->html->css(array('style.css')); ?>
</head>
<body>
        <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

in home.ctp in view

```
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>Welcome to my task management site.</p>
```

how to remove this error in CakePHP 2.5.5.

Comment: Change $html->css(...) to $this->Html->css(...)

Comment: `$html->css(...)` is OLD WAY use $this , Coz its NEW way :)

Comment: i am don't know about it bcoz i am a new in Cakephp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Change $html->css(...) to $this->Html->css(...)
```